# Issues with Displaying all images from specified Directory

Tags: php

I'm trying to display all images from a specified directory.

I have read many other questions about this, and I'm having one weird issue.

Here is my code.

```
  $dirname = 'C:/Projects/RMS/RMS/assets/img/MYADDS/clientslogos/';
  $images = glob($dirname."*.*");
  foreach($images as $image) 
  {
    echo'<img src="'.$image.'" />';
  }
```

Here is my result.

```
    <img src="C:/Projects/RMS/RMS/assets/img/MYADDS/clientslogos/3m_logo.jpg" />
    <img src="C:/Projects/RMS/RMS/assets/img/MYADDS/clientslogos/Bausch&lomb.logo.jpg" />
```

That is the correct path, but they are not displaying. I get console errors for each image, Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Projects/RMSICORP/RMSICORP/assets/img/MYADDS/clientslogos/3m_logo.jpg. This folder is in my project directory. I do this stuff all the time, I don't see what is wrong with this one.

When I view in chrome dev tools and click the image link, it will open with this path:

```
http://localhost:63879/C:/Projects/RMS/RMS/assets/img/MYADDS/clientslogos/3m_logo.jpg
```

If I remove the `http://localhost:63879/` it displays the image.

Any ideas why the direct path i.e. `<img src="C:/Projects/RMS/RMS/assets/img/MYADDS/clientslogos/3m_logo.jpg" />` does not work?

Comment: when u execute something the path will consider from the localhost itself. If your file inside ur executable file path those images will be displayed

Comment: what is the root path of your website? Even if you do get it to work with the absolute path, it will only work on the machine where the files are stored as those files will not exist on other computers.

Comment: Haha you read my mind,  I use define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); and then use ROOT./assets/img/MYADDS/clientslogos/ for my image path, but I was getting this error, so I tried using the absolute path to try to resolve the issue first.